# How can I give background color to the text content inside a div in my html page.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not need to give background color to the entire div. I only need the background color where there is any text content.Please help me.

Comment: e.g. `p { background: yellow; }`

Comment: is the text content surrounded by a `<p>` tag? Could you provide some code?

Comment: wrap it in a `<span>` or `<p>` tag and set background color of that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped you Googled "CSS Text Highlight".

```
<p class="intro">
    Highlighting text on a web page can help bring important information immediately to
    the readers attention e.g., "<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">This text
    should is highlighted in yellow and probably caught your eye first.</span>"
</p>
```

Please see: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001391.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps or for more better solution you can provide your fiddle

```
div {
height:2em; 
width:20em;
background-color:#333;
text-align:center;}

div span.textContent {
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF; }
```

Comment: suppose I have two lines in my text and my first line contains only two letters, the background color for the first line covers the entire width. Is there any way to give background color to only these two letters?

Comment: can you please create fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) to explain exactly how your code is...

Comment: if I understood proper than this should help you more http://jsfiddle.net/FB3yf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use span tag and apply background-color:#FFFF00;

```
<span style="background-color: #FFFF00;">In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation.</span>
```

This will look like,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need specify the backgroun-color property

```
#box{
    background-color : red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/EFzNq/

Comment: how this example can be useful to the OP?